# Pandas pivot table arrangement no aggregation

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pivot

I want to pivot a pandas dataframe without aggregation, and instead of presenting the pivot index column vertically I want to present it horizontally. I tried with `pd.pivot_table` but I'm not getting exactly what I wanted.

```
data = {'year': [2011, 2011, 2012, 2013, 2013],
        'A': [10, 21, 20, 10, 39],
        'B': [12, 45, 19, 10, 39]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
print df
    A   B  year
0  10  12  2011
1  21  45  2011
2  20  19  2012
3  10  10  2013
4  39  39  2013
```

But I want to have:

```
year      2011     2012      2013
cols     A    B   A    B    A    B
0       10    12  20   19   10   10
1       21    45  NaN  NaN  39   39
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can first create column for new index by [`cumcount`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html), then [`stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) with [`unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.unstack.html):

```
df['g'] = df.groupby('year')['year'].cumcount()
df1 = df.set_index(['g','year']).stack().unstack([1,2])
print (df1)

year  2011        2012        2013      
         A     B     A     B     A     B
g                                       
0     10.0  12.0  20.0  19.0  10.0  10.0
1     21.0  45.0   NaN   NaN  39.0  39.0
```

If need set columns names use [`rename_axis`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/whatsnew.html#changes-to-rename) (new in `pandas` `0.18.0`):

```
df['g'] = df.groupby('year')['year'].cumcount()
df1 = df.set_index(['g','year'])
        .stack()
        .unstack([1,2])
        .rename_axis(None)
        .rename_axis(('year','cols'), axis=1)
print (df1)
year  2011        2012        2013      
cols     A     B     A     B     A     B
0     10.0  12.0  20.0  19.0  10.0  10.0
1     21.0  45.0   NaN   NaN  39.0  39.0
```

Another solution with [`pivot`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.pivot.html), but you need swap first and second level of `Multiindex` in columns by [`swaplevel`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.swaplevel.html) and then sort it by [`sort_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sort_index.html):

```
df['g'] = df.groupby('year')['year'].cumcount()
df1 = df.pivot(index='g', columns='year')
df1 = df1.swaplevel(0,1, axis=1).sort_index(axis=1)
print (df1)
year  2011        2012        2013      
         A     B     A     B     A     B
g                                       
0     10.0  12.0  20.0  19.0  10.0  10.0
1     21.0  45.0   NaN   NaN  39.0  39.0
print (df1)

year  2011        2012        2013      
         A     B     A     B     A     B
g                                       
0     10.0  12.0  20.0  19.0  10.0  10.0
1     21.0  45.0   NaN   NaN  39.0  39.0
```

Comment: how to avoid printing `g` in the final dataframe?

Comment: use `df = df.rename_axis(None)` or `df.index.name=None`

Answer (score 5):

`groupby('year')` so I can `reset_index` to get index values of `0` and `1`.  Then do a bunch of clean up.

```
df.groupby('year')['A', 'B'] \
    .apply(lambda df: df.reset_index(drop=True)) \
    .unstack(0).swaplevel(0, 1, 1).sort_index(1)
```

[image]