# Create new columns from information on rows in Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pivot-table

So I have a Pandas dataframe with the following structure:

| ClientId | Product | Quantity |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 01 | Apples | 2 |
| 01 | Oranges | 3 |
| 01 | Bananas | 1 |
| 02 | Apples | 4 |
| 02 | Bananas | 2 |

and would like to get this df to look like:

| ClientId | Product_Apples | Quantity_Apples | Product_Oranges | Quantity_Oranges | Product_Bananas | Quantity_Bananas |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 01 | 1 | 2 | 1 | 3 | 1 | 1 |
| 02 | 1 | 4 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 2 |

where the columns starting with Product are binary variables.

What would be the Python code for this transformation?

Comment: What you have tried so far?

Comment: Regular one-hot encoding to the variable Product but I also want to transform other columns @shaikmoeed

Comment: Does this answer your questions? [pandas-pivot-table-arrangement-no-aggregation](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38606393/8353711)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your dataset is a pandas dataframe, you can try this:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'ClientID': ['01']*3 + ['02']*2,
    'Product': ['Apples', 'Oranges', 'Bananas', 'Apples', 'Bananas'],
    'Quantity': [2, 3, 1, 4, 2]
})

df['product_cnt'] = 1

# solution 1
df.pivot(index='ClientID', columns='Product', values=['Quantity', 'product_cnt']).fillna(0)

# solution 2
df_products = df.pivot(index='ClientID', columns='Product', values='product_cnt').fillna(0).add_prefix('Product_')
df_qty = df.pivot(index='ClientID', columns='Product', values='Quantity').fillna(0).add_prefix('Quantity_')
df_products.merge(df_qty, on='ClientID', how='left')
```